# drupal template files in different folders for different content types

Tags: theming

I'm trying to get Drupal to scan multiple directories to find template files for pages and nodes. I have a content type called "contest". I have a node with the path of "http://mysite.com/contest/test 
I'd like to have a folder structure like:

```
templates
    page
        page.tpl.php
        page-front.tpl.php
    node
        node.tpl.php
    contest
        contest.tpl.php
        contest-test.tpl.php
```

Drupal is not finding contest tpl's.

Answer (score 1):

See http://drupal.org/node/1089656 for more information on the possible file names that Drupal will recognize by default.

Drupal will not recognize `contest.tpl.php` as it is not one of the patterns that it recognizes.  If `contest.tpl.php` is an override of node.tpl.php then you should name it `node--contest.tpl.php`

If you want to override a page template in the same manner, see this previous post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194109/drupal-7-candidate-page-tpl-name-for-particular-custom-content-type-entry/5194364#5194364

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to have a different directory for each template file that is specific for a content type, as Drupal will look for those template files in the same directory where the base template file is.
For example, if the template file is one of the suggested files for node.tpl.php, then both node.tpl.php and the suggested template file must be in the same directory.